# How to add class to body tag on app webview?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, webview

I am using a WordPress plugin in order to display a popup on website version and everything works fine. Currently a Flutter Android app is under development, and it has to retrieve single blog posts from WordPress site, in a webview. The problem is that I do not want to show the popup on the app webview.

This is the PHP/JS code I added through WordPress functions.php:

```
function noPopupWebview() {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'wv') !== false) {
   $code = "<script> var body = document.body;
   body.classList.add('body--webview'); </script>";
   echo $code;
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'noPopupWebview', 1);
```

And then, I would hide the popup through CSS. The issue here is that I always get this error in console, failing to add the body--webview class to body tag:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

If I test JS in console, it works, adding the class correctly.

No problem with PHP, I can see JS added in the webview HTML source code.

How can I fix that?
Thank you in advance,

Alberto

Comment: check if body and then add class. also include this script inside a document on load event.

Comment: Hi @AkhilAravind thanks for your reply. How can I make it on load event?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event   this link will help